# Can we expect the discovery of something that moves faster than light/photons?

Tags: string-theory, photons, faster-than-light

As our knowledge on M-Theory improves in the times ahead which may unfold some warped dimension, can we expect the discovery of something that moves faster than light/photons?

Comment: It would have to be something incredibly tacky.

Comment: String theory (which is not proven) is based on special relativity, so it's very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

String theories respect symmetries of the 4d Poincare group, including those that result in special relativity. As such, faster than light particles are expected to be absent in nature, if string theory is correct.